# 2C2P facebook social commerce

Tags: facebook, commerce

Recently looking into available payment gateways in Thailand. 2C2P came up, along with Facebook beginning testing mid-2016. Other than a few articles, could not find anything else about it.

Is this a thing? Are there technical documents I'm not finding regarding setting up a page for an established company in Thailand to accept payments via 2C2P via a page? Only documentation I can find are with Stripe or Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

This service call Qwik. You can find more at https://www.facebook.com/qwikasia/